# PHP processing image with MIME type application/x-gzip

Tags: php, image

In my application I process links to various websites and download images that are present on those websites into my database. I have trouble processing [this image](http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/lemonade-970_29794.jpg). It looks like it's JPEG, but `imagecreatefromjpeg()` returns an error

> Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x1f 0x8b

I finally found working solution to get true file type, which is

```
$file = "http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/lemonade-970_29794.jpg"
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
```

which returns `application/x-gzip; charset=binary`

I'm not sure what to do with that. I guess it's somehow cached into gzip and the browser can work with that and that's why the image is normally loaded inside browser. But what can be done in PHP to download that file into some usual image type file? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure (hence the comment, not an answer ;)) but a wild guess is that if you load the file into a file info resource it will receive the compressed version. I'd suggest first downloading the file (so the server decompresses it when downloading), then load it into to gd lib.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out myself. This works

```
$file = gzencode("http://www.inc.com/uploaded_files/image/lemonade-970_29794.jpg");
$image = imagecreatefromstring($file);
```

Comment: it should be not working. gzencode is encoding the string, but you should decode the gzip request,not encoding it again .

Answer (score 0):

my working solution

```
//detect if gzip
function _is_gzip_jpeg($data){
  $gzip_check="\x1f\x8b";
      return substr( $data, 0, strlen($gzip_check) ) === $gzip_check;
}

//create tmp file
$local = tempnam("/tmp", "ic_");
//downloaded content
$content = file_get_contents($url);

//check if gzip
if(_is_gzip_jpeg($content)){
  //if yes, decode it and save.
  file_put_contents($local, gzdecode($content ));
}else{ 
  //not gzip content, save it to tmp file
  file_put_contents($local, $content );
}

//check meta
$meta = getimagesize($local);

//....get resource
if($meta['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
  $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($local);
} else if ($meta['mime'] == 'image/png') {
  $image = @imagecreatefrompng($local);
} else if ($meta['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
  $image = @imagecreatefromgif($local);
}else{
  $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($local);
}

//do what you need to do here......
```